# Not able to use JIL Serializer ExcludeNulls Option

Tags: c#, .net-core, mediatypeformatter, jil

I am not able to use JIL's Exclude Null option. Instead, I get an exception:

> JIL.DeserializationException: 'Expected digit'

[image]

Below are code snippets.

```
public Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
{
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

    var request = context.HttpContext.Request; if (request.ContentLength == 0)
    {
        if (context.ModelType.GetTypeInfo().IsValueType)
            return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(Activator.CreateInstance(context.ModelType));
        else return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(null);
    }

    var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;//do we need to get this from the request im not sure yet 

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body))
    {
        var model =  Jil.JSON.Deserialize(reader, context.ModelType, Jil.Options.ExcludeNulls);
        return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(model);
    }
}
```

1) Model type

```
public class PaymentTypeBORequest
{   
    public int pkId { get; set; }        
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool isSystem { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }           
}
```

2) JSON String:

```
{
    "pkId":null,
    "description": "Adjustment",
    "isSystem": true,
    "isActive": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [description for the `excludeNulls` option](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil/blob/master/Jil/Options.cs#L353) is:

> whether or not to **write** object members whose value is `null`

(emphasis mine)

This suggests that it only affects *serialisation* operations and not *deserialisation* operations.

When *serialising* an object with `excludeNulls` set to `true`, Jil will not write properties to the JSON if they have `null` values. In your example, you're *deserialising* into a `PaymentTypeBORequest` object, which itself does not support `null` values for the `pkId` property, as it's not nullable.

In order to resolve your specific issue, you can simply set `pkId` to be a nullable `int`, like so:

```
public class PaymentTypeBORequest
{   
    public int? pkId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

If you want to also allow `null` for the non-nullable `isSystem` and `isActive` properties, you can perform the same operations on those fields.